# ES6 modules: get list of dependency files recursively

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I have main.js file, that imports ES6 modules, that, in turn, also depend on other modules. And I use rollup.js to bundle all the modules into single file.

**How do I get list of all the files that my main.js is dependent upon?**

I want to use this list in gulp.watch to automatically run rollup task and have updated bundle each time any of the modules have been changed. I know I can watch the whole /js directory, but is there a way to be more specific?

Comment: The best option really would be for Rollup to implement this: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/284 It's the one that knows what files depend on what.

Answer (score 4):

The `bundle` object contains a `modules` property which is a list of objects representing the modules it contains. So if you have files like this...

```js
// src/main.js
import foo from './foo.js';
console.log( foo );

// src/foo.js
export default 42;
```

...you can get the IDs like so:

```js
rollup.rollup({
  entry: 'src/main.js'
}).then( bundle => {
  console.log( bundle.modules );
  // [{
  //   id: 'path/to/src/main.js'
  // },{
  //   id: 'path/to/src/foo.js'
  // }]
});
```

You can use that to determine which files to watch.